# Remove a string in array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to run this program once to delete the first "Banana" and run this program the second time to delete the second "Banana".
The case is when I now running my code, it will only delete the second "Banana" in the array and stops.

Also I want to print the original array before the delete any elements.I used "System.out.println(" " + array)" but it ends up with showing some garbled code.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] array = {"Fish", "Banana", "Carrot", "Pinapple", null, "Banana" };
        String[] newArr = null;
        System.out.println("The string is showing as : " );      
        System.out.println(array.length);
        System.out.println(" " + array);
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] == "Banana"){
                newArr = new String[array.length - 1];
                for(int index = 0; index < i; index++){
                    newArr[index] = array[index];
                }
                for(int j = i; j < array.length - 1; j++){
                    newArr[j] = array[j+1];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After deleting a element the string is showing as : " );      
        for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
            System.out.print(newArr[i] + " ");
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that `array[i] == "Donkey"` should be `array[i].equals( "Banana")`.  You should learn about string comparison and fix this.  But the problem that's causing your bug is that every time you find a `Banana`, you're making a new array for `newArr`, instead of using the one from the previous iteration.

Comment: They 1) why are you looking for "Donkey" and 2) you are comparing Strings incorrectly.  Use `equals()`

Comment: @WJS That won't help in this case, because all the strings are literals, so `==` will work.  The problem is that a new `newArr` is being created for each `Banana/Donkey`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  Actually the OP should use `"Banana".equals(array[i])` since the array contains a null.

Comment: @WJS Ooh, good point.

Comment: Oh, my bad I changed some of my variables to make it looks more clearly, the question was asking me to remove "donkey" in arrays. I changed my code so it asks to remove "Banana" now.

Comment: use `Arrays.toString(array)` to print the array

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you try to create an empty array, do not write `String[] newArr = null;`
change it into

```
    String[] newArr = new String[array.length];
    //if you want the size of newArr similar to the size of array
```

Secondly, if you want to print all values in an array, do not print the array object directly

```
    System.out.println(" " + array); //do not use this
    //if you wish to print all values in array
```

Instead, print the value one by one

```
    for(String element: array) {
        System.out.print(" " + element); //this command will print a space
    //followed by one value in array
    }
```

Thirdly, I assume that `if(array[i] == "Donkey")` is a typo. Because I do not see String `"Donkey"` in `array`

Fourthly, to compare an element of String, we can't use `if(array[i] == "Banana")` we use `if(array[i].equals("Banana"))` instead

Lastly, because you put an element of `null` in `array` you need to make sure that the element in `array` is not `null` before you can compare the value with String `"Banana"`
Therefore we need to write down `if(array[i] != null)` before `if(array[i].equals("Banana"))`

The complete codes are

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"Fish", "Banana", "Carrot", "Pinapple", null, "Banana" };
    String[] newArr = new String[array.length];
    System.out.println("The string is showing as : " );      
    System.out.println(array.length);
    for(String element: array) {
        System.out.print(" " + element);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] != null){
            if(array[i].equals("Banana")) {
                newArr[i] = null;
            } else {
                newArr[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nAfter deleting a element the string is showing as : " );      
    for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(newArr[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for printing the array will be using
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr))`. This should take care of printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] array = {"Fish", "Banana", "Carrot", "Pinapple", null, "Banana" };
    String[] newArr = null;
    System.out.println("The string is showing as : " );      
    System.out.println(array.length);
    System.out.println(" " + array);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].equals("Banana")){
            newArr = new String[array.length - 1];
            for(int index = 0; index < i; index++){
                newArr[index] = array[index];
            }
            for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length - 1; j++){
                newArr[j] = array[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After deleting a element the string is showing as : " );      
    for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(newArr[i] + " ");
    }                
}
```

}